# What exactly robustness of a solution mean?

Tags: terminology, stability

One usually comes across many research papers that talk about robustness, but since I have never been introduced to this term formally in my education, I am not sure what distinguishes a robust solution/condition from a non-robust one.

Is the idea of robustness connected to strong/weak solutions of a problem?

Comment: Robust means immune to perturbations/noise/out side interferences (not wave interference, daily life interference...).

Answer (score 1):

Essentially it means that if you make small changes in the input parameters you get small changes in the output values. That is there is roughly bounded by a linear or polynomial relation and is not exponentially related. In the latter case, we say the solution blows up. In the former case we say it is robust and as one commenter has said, 'immune from perturbations'.